# How to create a Bean type programmatically?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm building a module that creates set of blocks using [Bean](https://drupal.org/project/bean) module. How do I can create a `Bean Type` programmatically in order to be able to create the blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bean uses [ctools plugins](http://stevector.com/ctools_plugins_presentation/#1) for its types. Per [the docs](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/bean!bean.api.php/7.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_bean_types().
 *
 * Beans uses ctools plugins to define the block types.
 * All plugin files must be registered in the .info file.
 */
function hook_bean_types() {
  $plugins = array();
  $plugins['plugin_key'] = array(
    'label' => t('Title'),
    'description' => t('Description'),
    // This is optional. Set it to TRUE if you do not want the plugin to be
    // displayed in the UI.
    'abstract' => FALSE,
    'handler' => array(
      'class' => 'ClassName',
      'parent' => 'bean',
      // This should be pointing to the path of your custom bean plugin module.
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'example_bean') . '/plugins',
      // Class files should be named accordingly in order to support ctools
      // autoloading procedures.
      'file' => 'ClassName.class.php',
    ),
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

Comment: How does this show how to attach a new bundle to the bean entity type? I don't think I understand...

Comment: If you put this code in a module, it'll attach a new bundle to the entity type @Felix. Not really much more to explain, that's how the module developers chose to implement it, as a ctools plugin

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple.

---

```
<?php
$bean = bean_create(array('type' => 'my_bean_type'));
$bean->label = 'Administrative Label';
$bean->title = 'Bean Title';
$bean->delta = 'bean-machine-name';
$bean->field_block_content = array(
'en' => array(array(
  'value' => '<p>Text</p>',
  'format' => 'wysiwyg_editor',
)),
);
$bean->save();
?>
```

Comment: I know this. I don't know how to create the Bean type. I mean I don't want to create the `my_bean_type` in admin UI

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code in `bean_admin_ui_type_form_submit()` I've put together the following function:

```
/**
 * @param $machine_name
 * @param $label
 * @param string $desc
 */
function create_bean_type($machine_name, $label, $desc = '') {
  $plugin_info = array(
    'name' => '',
    'label' => '',
    'description' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'editable' => TRUE,
    'handler' => array(
      'info_file' => TRUE,
      'class' => 'BeanCustom',
      'parent' => 'bean',
      'file' => 'BeanCustom.class.php',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'bean_admin_ui') . '/plugins',
    ),
  );
  $bean_type = new BeanCustom($plugin_info);
  $bean_type->type = $machine_name;
  $bean_type->setLabel($label);
  $bean_type->setDescription($desc);
  $bean_type->save(TRUE);
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

I've not used the `_bean_admin_default_plugin()` function in case this code is running with the bean_admin_ui module disabled.

You can use this function like this:

```
create_bean_type('baked_bean', 'Baked Bean', 'A baked bean is a bundle attached to the bean entity type. Also if you eat too many you may fart.');
```